# Making the whole photo in focues using Nikon D7100 with nikkor 18-105 mm

Tags: focus, nikon-d7100, hyperfocal-distance

[image]Can anyone help me in how to make the whole photo in focus ??
I'm using Nikon D7100 with  Nikkor 18-105 mm.

Updated

Comment: Please post a sample photo - there are various things you could be doing wrong, but it's very hard to tell without seeing an example.

Comment: Updated the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to focus the lens at its "hyperfocal distance" for the selected aperture. The hyperfocal distance is the focus distance which places the furthest edge of the depth of field at infinity. (Depth of field is the range of distances which appear sharp in a picture).

A loose rule of thumb is to use a small aperture and focus 1/3 the way into the picture. There are online calculators such as the one at http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/hyperfocal-distance.htm to give you better results.

Comment: Nikkor 18-105 has no infinity mark , then how ?

Comment: Hmm... in that case just use a small aperture, focus partway through the scene, and you'll just have to get used doing trial and error by zooming in on an image on playback to find what's in focus and then changing focus point or aperture. Hopefully if you do this enough you'll get a feel for what settings to use.

Comment: @FalahSalih what I've done before is if I knew I wanted to use, say, f/11 18mm hyperfocal distance, I measured it before hand and marked in on my lens with masking tape and sharpie. Nikon's super zoom lenses are not designed for precise manual focus though, so it's difficult to nail it every time. A few times I've duct-taped my lens in that position so it can't lose f/11 hyperfocal focus.